# go vet complaining about loop variable being captured by func literal

Tags: go

One of the common newbies' mistakes documented in go github's [page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables), is neglecting to pass a loop variable as a parameter to the goroutine (in which the program's output could show unexpected results:

```golang
   for _, val := range values {
      go func() {
/* here is where go-vet complains loop variable v captured by func literal*/
          fmt.Println(val) 
      }()
   }
```

> there is a very good chance that when you run this code you will see
> the last element printed for every iteration instead of each value in
> sequence, because the goroutines will probably not begin executing
> until after the loop.

So the proposed solution is (as said) to pass the actual loop var as goroutine parameter:

```golang
for _, val := range values {
    go func(val interface{}) {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }(val)
}
```

So what does `go-vet` nag about in the below example?

```golang
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        go func(emp int) {
            for range ch {
                rcv := <-ch
         /*  loop variable i captured by func literal */
                fmt.Printf("employee %d received signal %d\n", i, rcv)
            }
        }(i)
    }

}
```

Comment: you should also note that your `for range` is probably incorrect, as you're skipping every other element passed through the channel

Comment: thanks. any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Don't receive a second time in the loop, use the range expression. See the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4)

Answer (score 5):

This is the line:

```
fmt.Printf("employee %d received signal %d\n", i, rcv)
```

Here, use `emp` instead of `i`. You're passing in the loop variable as `emp` to the goroutine, but you seem to have forgotten to use it.